# How is multiple lookbehind and lookahead regex working in this example?

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex:

```
(?<=Hour\n)(.*)(?=\n)(?<=Receipt).*(?=Number)
```

And this is my string:

```
Hour
Lead-Analyst
ReceiptJobNumber
```

I wanna get out **Lead-Analyst** and **Job** .

But it does not work. I tried here https://regex101.com/

Comment: What's the goal? Extract the data or replace it?

Comment: Lookarounds are zero-length assertions. `(?=\n)(?<=Receipt)` matches before newlines if preceded by `Receipt` which does not occur in your input. It would match [here](https://regex101.com/r/nWXa1D/1). Guess you were looking for something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/Wl7pWN/1).

Comment: regarding answer 1 : The goal ist to extract it . But does it make any difference ? lol Regarding answer 2 : Yes your second solution works. But it's a pain to always start from the very first letter. I wished lookarounds would not be zero based which means in our example the regex will always start from Hour even it would just need to start from Receipt

Comment: If you need to replace, all these lookarounds make sense but for extraction it is more efficient to prefer [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) wherever possible. Also see [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQ3HHt/1) (only one lookahead is needed to cover the overlapping).

Comment: Regarding your perfomrance concern. Indeed you can use the [`\G` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) for even better performance. It anchors the match to the position where the previous match ended. I think this will be the most efficient solution for your task: [`Hour\n(.*)\nReceipt|\G(?!^)(\w+)Number`](https://regex101.com/r/PoCYw4/1)

Comment: And the [Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##dVHLTsMwEDyTr9jmUNkUXLgSUoQQTxWEKJwISG5qiotjR45Di6DfXjaPFhrKXMbedWZ2NhP@zncno7fFQiapsQ4mWGC5k4pZMRYzds1d/Cps4P3Tv@XOCasDz4sVzzI4nfEkVQI@PUCk@VDJGDLHHdK7kSNIuNRk4KzU48cn4Hac0fpxgRepuYKqDaUDhOBfmNxGkSZsmyLdiVjI1H1F0Tk5aj1TEkXTDr3Jk6GwfrBZKqtoqaV9bws64PcFH@0e47uPzK2Ktf6VGf7RbIjX4SGtOVxWWGySVCpBygg7q/L1Q//@sn95c0qbc9Z7xvVUHC5FWV0hVQS6YZjpK1oBqR8yFBwRSlftn@0W6HZhgGlFwkzuWIqaTmnin@VKVeYH4OMWlmJja/KU7NFfvmveZQJjgaAOSBx7P0A6DNcFTkyuHaHY6nRoY6AC8oVI6MEetNsNZ0lbocbZ8KuGa4UNWZoCxT@FsFfG8qticZTFlfqNYAXm3uZbdZp788XiGw)

Comment: In the `\G` pattern the right side of the alternation `|\G...` requires the left to have matched before (the left side is not dependent). If the condition is to always match both, maybe you can simply use [`Hour\n(.*)\nReceipt(\w+)Number`](https://regex101.com/r/xRzqjE/1) - hope it helped.

Comment: doublebubble, I mean @bobblebubble, your comments would be more coherent if combined in an answer.

Comment: \G does not work in my case somehow. I just put it after the | like that |\G but it broke my regex. but apart from that Thanks a lot

Comment: @CarySwoveland I would have answered, if I found a point to build my answer around :) I don't see how essaying about all these ideas without exactly knowing how OPs input can look like, how is the real data, in what cases which parts need to match (get extracted)... I'm glad it helped however!